# How to use a WordPress shortcode in a URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, shortcode, url-parameters

I have created a WordPress shortcode in `functions.php` that looks like this:

```
function user_email() {
}
add_shortcode( 'user_email', 'user_email' );
```

This captures the logged-in WordPress user's email address. I want to pass that email address in a query string, so the end result would look like this:

```
https://ofcoursebooks.com/bmf?email=ashli@example.com
```

To do that, I was hoping to pass the email address via the short code:

```
https://ofcoursebooks.com/bmf?email=[user_email]
```

That doesn't seem to be working though... it just passes the actual `[user_email]` text.

What did I miss?

Comment: Why do you need a shortcode to get the user's email address? Can you not just use something like `$user = wp_get_current_user(); $user->user_email` to get their email address which can then be echoed where necessary e.g. in the query string of your URL.